# Why does typing "./" in sh produce "permission denied"?

Tags: shell, arm

Perfectly incidentally, I typed `./` into a sh shell today running ARM linux and it produced "permission denied" as an error, as opposed to "Is a directory" which is the usual error.

ARM Linux in sh:

```
[root@zynq DEBUG]# ./
-sh: ./: Permission denied
[root@zynq DEBUG]# uname -a
Linux zynq 3.8.0-xilinx #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon May 19 13:01:00 PDT 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
[root@zynq DEBUG]# echo $SHELL
/bin/sh
```

Debian Jessie in bash:

```
root@hotbox:~# ./
bash: ./: Is a directory
root@hotbox:~# uname -a
Linux hotbox 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt9-3~deb8u1 (2015-04-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@hotbox:~# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

I understand that I'm attempting to execute a directory, but I'm curious: Why does sh produces a permission error?

Comment: What is `sh`? It's usually linked to something else, what?

Comment: @muru `/bin/sh -> busybox
`.   Busybox, apparently. Good catch.

Answer (score 7):

If I were to guess, your `sh` favours simplicity or performance over user friendliness. The "permission denied" error is that provided by [`perror(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/perror.3posix), a standard function for printing an error message. For example:

```
$ cat foo.c       
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char* const args[] = { "/usr", NULL };
    if (execv(args[0], args))
        perror(args[0]);

    return 0;
}
$ gcc -o foo foo.c
$ ./foo
/usr: Permission denied
```

`bash` probably makes a check to see if the path is a directory. That will, of course, be slightly slower and be slightly longer code.

`bash`, `zsh`, etc. have more than one reason to make the check - they allow you to "run" a path to a directory to `cd` to it:

```
$ shopt -s autocd
$ cd /
$ pwd
/
$ /usr/share
cd /usr/share
$ pwd
/usr/share
```

---

In the case of `dash` (Debian's `/bin/sh` points to `/bin/dash`), that's pretty much the case. The code that executes the command is in [`shellexec()`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/exec.c#n685):

```c
if (strchr(argv[0], '/') != NULL) {
    tryexec(argv[0], argv, envp);
    e = errno;
} else {
// snip
exerror(EXEXIT, "%s: %s", argv[0], errmsg(e, E_EXEC));
```

That function calls [`errms()`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/error.c#n215):

```c
const char *
errmsg(int e, int action)
{
    if (e != ENOENT && e != ENOTDIR)
        return strerror(e);

    if (action & E_OPEN)
        return "No such file";
    else if (action & E_CREAT)
        return "Directory nonexistent";
    else
        return "not found";
}
```

[`strerror(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/strerror.3posix) is another standard function, like `perror`. `strerror` returns the error message, `perror` prints it directly.

Comment: Check it out with `strace -fv /bin/sh ./`.

Comment: And in this case, it's not dash, but BusyBox ash, which is specifically designed to minimize code size.

Comment: @Gilles I know it's Busybox ash. I'm just more "familiar" with `dash`'s source.